# Warning that my Async function is actually running synchronously in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, async-await

My first time writing async code in VB.NET although I've done it in Java.

I have a WinForm with multiple combo boxes that need to be populated. The queries take about 12-14 seconds to finish, which is way too long to block the UI. So instead of populating them in the onLoad event handler directly, I'm calling an Async function that returns a DataTable.

My question is that Visual Studio (2019) is giving me a warning on the async functions saying that the method lacks an Await operator.  I've tried removing "Async" from the function and but this way works. More importantly it's still taking 12 seconds before the UI appears. Why am I getting the error?  How do I make it actually run the queries in the background? I've included the onLoad sub and the DataTable query function.

```
Private Async Sub Part_Entry_Form_Inventory_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod.Name & " starting @ " & DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"))
    Me.TopMost = True
    Dim t1 = Await GetDataTable("SELECT BatchDate, Batchname 
                             FROM [Inventory_Batches] 
                             GROUP BY BatchDate, Batchname 
                             ORDER BY BatchDate; ", "Batch")
    ChooseBatch.DataSource = t1
    ChooseBatch.DisplayMember = "BatchName"
    ChooseBatch.ValueMember = "BatchDate"
    ChooseBatch.SelectedIndex = -1

    Dim t2 = Await GetDataTable("SELECT CatID, CatName
                           FROM [Parts_Inventory_Owned_Parts_Query]
                           GROUP BY CatID, CatName
                           ORDER BY CatName;", "Category")
    ChooseCatName.DataSource = t2
    ChooseCatName.DisplayMember = "CatName"
    ChooseCatName.ValueMember = "CatID"
    ChooseCatName.SelectedIndex = -1

    Dim t3 = Await GetDataTable("SELECT PartID, PartID + ' | ' + [partName] AS PartString
                             FROM [Part_List]
                             GROUP BY PartID, PartID + ' | ' + [partName]
                             ORDER BY PartID;", "Part")
    ChoosePartNum.DataSource = t3
    ChoosePartNum.DisplayMember = "PartString"
    ChoosePartNum.ValueMember = "PartID"
    ChoosePartNum.SelectedIndex = -1

    Dim t4=Await GetDataTable("SELECT ColorID, ColorName
                               FROM [Color_List]
                               ORDER BY ColorName;","Color")
    ChooseColor.DataSource = t4
    ChooseColor.DisplayMember = "ColorName"
    ChooseColor.ValueMember = "ColorID"
    ChooseColor.SelectedIndex = -1

    Dim t5 = Await GetDataTable("SELECT LocationID, LocationName
                                 FROM [Inventory_Locations]
                                 WHERE LinkedToSet Is Null AND LinkedToOrder Is Null
                                 ORDER BY [LocationName];", "Location")
    ChooseLocation.DataSource = t5
    ChooseLocation.DisplayMember = "LocationName"
    ChooseLocation.ValueMember = "LocationID"
    ChooseLocation.SelectedIndex = -1
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod.Name & " ending @ " & DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"))
End Sub

Async Function GetDataTable(sql As String, title As String) As Task(Of DataTable)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod.Name & " " & title & " starting @ " & DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss.fff"))
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.partmanagerdataConnectionString)
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, conn)
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    Dim tbl As New DataTable()
    adapter.Fill(tbl)
    Return tbl
End Function
```

The warning message appears as an underline highlighting each the function names (GetDataTable) and says,

> BC42356: This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run
>   synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await
>   non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work
>   on a background thread

FWIW I also tried putting this in the MyBase.Shown handler and it's worse

Comment: Show me where you used the Await keyword in the GetDataTable function

Comment: I did not put Await in the GetDataTable function. I thought I used Await to assign the function's return to a value in the calling procedure

Comment: Search how to make synchronous code (GetDataTable) async.  See Task,Run

Answer (score 4):

VB is complaining because you haven't used `Await` anywhere in `GetDataTable` yet you have declared it as `Async`

If you're coming from Java, async in the TAP sense should be easy to explain:

You know how, in Java you have to (or had to when I was coding it many years ago) declare that a method throws some exception and you have to be explicit about what it throws? The `Async` keyword is a bit like that. If you have a method in Java that throws, and you call it and you don't catch in that calling method then the calling method has to be declared as throws too.. and basically all the way up the call tree, if you never catch that exception your lowest-of-the-low method throws, then everything all the way up the tree to the very top (main) has to declare that it throws. `Async` as a modifier is similar; throughout your whole code if you mark something as `Async`, you mark everything else as `Async` all the way up the tree until you are outside your code.

You have to mark your method `Async` if you want to use await and should use `Await` if you want to properly wait on an async method. Microsoft provides the methods you're calling with `dataAdapter.Fill` and they *aren't* async, so you haven't actually called anything awaitable, so you haven't used `Await`, so vb is complaining that the GetDataTable is marked as async but doesn't await - just like Java would complain if you said a method throws SomeException when it doesn't.. So, if you're going to have your entire call tree be an async chain you either need to call an async method (and I don't think dataadapter has any) and await it, or you need to be the start of something async (Task.Run something synchronous) and await it (or return the Task so that something else can await it, but then you don't need the async modifier)

Awaiting async is a bit like throwing an uncaught exception; if you throw an exception your code stops where it is, picks up its ball and goes home up the call tree and out into code that is someone else's problem. Awaiting async behaves the same way, packing everything into a state machine (saving state) and going back up the tree til it disappears out of your code and the thread (probably a UI thread) goes back to what it was doing before (probably drawing a UI), making the app appear responsive/not hung. When the Task (returned by the async call you called in the lowest-low method) you're Awaiting on completes, the thread returns to where it left off, the saved state is loaded and things proceed as if the whole op was syncronous, it's just that in the interim while we were waiting the thread that kicked things off was free to go back to what it was doing before

In terms of what to do in your situation, you're probably going to have to do something like this in GetDataTable if you plan on doing any work inside GetDataTable after this completes:

```
Await Task.Run(Sub() adapter.Fill(x) )
```

Or this (called eliding - [see Stephen Cleary's blog for more info](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html)), if you don't do any work afterwards *and you're not inside a Using block*:

```
Return Task.Run(Sub() adapter.Fill(x) )
```

You skip marking the method as `Async` if you straight up return a Task, because Async is used to let the compiler know "this method will do some work, and await something and do more work, so it needs to be able to save state so it can come back". Returning a Task doesn't need to save state; awaiting a task and doing something afterwards needs to save state, so the calling method will probably be the one to do this

---

But consider also, instead of awaiting the first fill, then awaiting the second, then the third.. You could instead *not* await each one in turn but instead collect all your tasks (you're returned a Task when you Task.Run a syncronous method) for your various operations into a collection of Tasks, and then `Await Task.WhenAll(theListOfTasks)`. This means the tasks all start going simultaneously, when they are run and your code waits on all of them (essentially waiting on whichever turns out to be the longest one) and your code resumes executing when the last task finishes. Depending on how your database copes with the sudden influx of these multiple queries it might cut down that wait time a bit

---

Side note; when you write code that behaves in an Async way, name the method with an Async suffix, e.g. `GetDataTableAsync` - remember that it's more the case that "functions that can be used asyncy/be awaited should be named ...Async" rather than "functions that have the Async modifier should be named ...Async" - there's a subtle difference